# In Unity, I'm trying to understand what code gets generated when I attach scripts to GameObjects

Tags: unity

I'm trying to observe any file changes that happen when I attach a script to a GameObject.

I am able to attach a script to a GameObject, and verify that it was attached by looking at the console log. (In my case I attached MainPlayer to some random GameObject like WeaponCamera.)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string myName;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("I am alive and my name is " + myName);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

However, I don't see any actual code change (eg: line additions) to any files in my unity project (using git status or git diff). I would think that something would get updated in my repo, unless I'm misunderstanding how attachment works? For example, if someone else were to copy my repo and try it on their computer, shouldn't they have the attachment I just made?

Comment: What changes is usually a prefab or scene file. If the modified game object is not part of a prefab then the scene file is modified. To see it in git you must first save the scene/prefab.

Comment: I notice your debug log fires only at runtime, not design time. Are you attaching this script at runtime? Runtime changes to scene objects are not serialized to files.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I was able to see changes to MainScene.unity after doing File -> Save. The actual line changes are still kinda cryptic but this should do for now.